# TRIGGER with insert partial field

Tags: mysql, triggers

2 tables

```
 tb_product  :
    product_id, 
    product_size_values

    tb_product_category : 
    product_id , 
    category_id
```

product_size_values contains '41,42,46' or '44,45,46,47' or any values from 42 to 48 with coma separator ....

and the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_product_size AFTER UPDATE ON tb_product

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

 IF (NEW.product_size_values != OLD.product_size_values) THEN 

       INSERT INTO tb_product_category (product_id, product_size_values) 
       VALUES (NEW.product_id, 42) WHERE NEW.product_size_values LIKE  '%42%'
       ;

       INSERT INTO tb_product_category (product_id, product_size_values) 
       VALUES (NEW.product_id, 43) WHERE NEW.product_size_values LIKE  '%43%'
       ;

   END IF;

END //
```

of course the *WHERE NEW.product_size_values LIKE* does not work

my normal query to do that actually (without trigger ) is

```
 insert into tb_product_category (product_id,category_id) 
    select product_id,42 
    from tb_product 
    where product_size_values like '%42%' ;

    insert into tb_product_category (product_id,category_id) 
    select product_id,43
    from tb_product 
    where product_size_values like '%43%' ;
```

and **NO** the comma separated field cannot be changed

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you cannot use a like test in a conditional statement and you cannot use a where clause with values and an insert select seems wasteful. You may be able to ditch the like clause and use and instr or locate to check values for example

```
drop table if exists tb_product,tb_product_category;

create table tb_product
(product_id int, 
product_size_values varchar(20));

insert into tb_product values
(1,'42');

create table tb_product_category 
(product_id int, 
category_id int);

drop trigger if exists trg_product_size;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_product_size AFTER UPDATE ON tb_product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.product_size_values != OLD.product_size_values) THEN 
        if instr(NEW.product_size_values,42) > 0 then
       INSERT INTO tb_product_category (product_id, category_id) values (new.product_id,42);
       end if;
      if INSTR(NEW.product_size_values,43) > 0 then
       INSERT INTO tb_product_category (product_id, category_id) values (new.product_id,43);
      end if;
   END IF;
END $$
delimiter ;

select product_size_values from tb_product;
update tb_product
    set product_size_values = '42,43' where product_id = 1;

select * from tb_product_Category;

+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          42 |
|          1 |          43 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Works as coded. You may wish to change the insert logic to check for existence before inserting to avoid duplicates.